# Object invoked has disconnected from its client

Tags: excel, vba

I have search through all similar questions and can't find one that matches my situation.  I have the below code to attempt to apply a filter, if the filter returned no results enters "No Results Found" on my errors sheet.  If the filter is able to be applied it copies six columns from the source table, to a separate errors sheet.  I have the exact same code in another workbook and there is works fine.  It was working in this workbook, but now it is giving me the "Object Invoked has disconnected error"  The lines that are giving me the error are the the actual copy and paste lines that are between "Else" and "End if", and even if I pull those lines and run them separately they still give the error.

```
Sub fHrsErrors()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim HrsFilter As Range
    
    With Sheets("Paycode Checks").ListObjects("PCTable").AutoFilter.Range
        .AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:= _
        "<>0"
        
        Set HrsFilter = .Resize(.Rows.Count, 1) _
                      .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        
        If HrsFilter.Cells.Count = 1 Then
            Sheets("Hours Errors").Range("A2").Value = "No Results Found"
            
        Else
        
            Range("PCTable[Employee]").Copy
            Sheets("Hours Errors").Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            
            Range("PCTable[PayCode]").Copy
            Sheets("Hours Errors").Range("B2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            
            Range("PCTable[Sum of Wrkd_Hours]").Copy
            Sheets("Hours Errors").Range("C2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

            Range("PCTable[FF Hrs]").Copy
            Sheets("Hours Errors").Range("D2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            
            Range("PCTable[CGC Hrs]").Copy
            Sheets("Hours Errors").Range("E2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            
            Range("PCTable[Hrs Diff]").Copy
            Sheets("Hours Errors").Range("F2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


        End If
        
    End With
  
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you recently converted from one excel version to another?

Comment: Are your Range Names defined in this sheet? What happens when you test Debug.Print Range("PCTable[Employee]").address? Does it work if you specify the Sheet? As in Debug.Print Sheets("Paycode Checks").Name and Debug.Print Sheets("Paycode Checks").Range("PCTable[Employee]").address?

Comment: @Mackanachi I have not recently updated, nothing has changed on my end.  It just randomly stopped working.

Comment: @dbmitch as far as I can tell the debugs you listed do nothing.  No Response.   All range names are defined and the code was previously working.  I didn't change or update anything, but now when it is run it either errors out and gives me the Object Invoked error, or it just completely closes Excel with no error message.

Comment: I think I found a possible cause, but I don't know the solution.  If I remove the table and recreate it manually the above code starts working again, however when I create the table via vba my code above doesn't recognize the table.  The code I am using to create the table is:  Sheets("Paycode Checks").ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Sheets("Paycode Checks").Range("$A:$K"), , xlYes).Name = _
        "PCTable"

Comment: When I use your code for creating the table, it makes every single row in the sheet part of the table.  Granted, this still doesn't reproduce the error that you are getting but I would consider using two variables to get the last row and last column, or depending on how your data is set up you could work with the current region, and see if that helps at your end.